# Python: Thread Execution time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Is it possible to set execution time for thread in Python.???? like,If that time period get completed I can stop that thread and create new instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    # print "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
    print pool.map(f, range(10))

    # print same numbers in arbitrary order
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        print i

    # evaluate "f(20)" asynchronously
    res = pool.apply_async(f, (20,))      # runs in *only* one process
    print res.get(timeout=1)              # prints "400"
```

From the multiprocessing [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).